# Как правильно сделать постоянную проверку ячейки на заполнение?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, таблицы

Я написал так, но выдаёт ошибку Exceeded maximum stack depth (строка 9, файл Код):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell1 = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
  var cell2 = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1");
 
    if (cell1 != "") {
    cell2.setValue("Дороу")
}
  else myFunction()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы зацикливаете выполлнение рекрсией.

Можно добавить формулу на проверку пустого значения

```
=ISBLANK(A1)
```

или

```
=IF(A1<>"";"Дороу";)
```

Постоянно что-то проверять скриптами не получится. У них либо ограничение по времени исполнения, либо они работают как формулы, либо они будут отрабатывать, но ни при всех типах изменений `A1`